# Find whether point is inside a triangle (2D)

Tags: java, geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I am writing the Quick Hull algorithm which includes checking whether a point lies inside a triangle. For this purpose, I have created the following two functions which return true if the point is inside and false otherwise.

However, the results are quiet unexpected in the sense some of the points are classified correctly while some are not and I can't figure out the problem. Could someone please help me verify if the code i have written is correct. The approach is that I am using vectors to find out if a point lies on the same side as the vertex for each edge of the triangle.
The code is :

```
public boolean ptInside(Point first, Point last, Point mx, Point cur) {
        boolean b1 = pointInside(first, last, mx, cur);
        boolean b2 = pointInside(last, mx, first, cur);
        boolean b3 = pointInside(first, mx, last, cur);
        return b1 && b2 && b3;

    }

    public boolean pointInside(Point first, Point last, Point mx, Point cur) {
        int x1 = last.xCo - first.xCo;
        int y1 = last.yCo - first.yCo;
        int x2 = mx.xCo - first.xCo;
        int y2 = mx.yCo - first.yCo;
        int x3 = cur.xCo - first.xCo;
        int y3 = cur.yCo - first.yCo;
        int cross1 = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1;
        int cross2 = x1 * y3 - x3 * y1;
        if (cross1 * cross2 > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
```

Comment: 1. write tests (especially around the borders) 2. make sure they pass.

Answer (score 6):

I would simply create a Polygon, and use its [contains(Point)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains%28java.awt.Point%29) method. Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Your ordering of points for the calculation of b3 is incorrect.  You need to keep (first, last, mx) in cyclical order.  Otherwise you have reversed the sense of the computation.